# Main Activity Not Found Error in One Activity But not The other?

Tags: android

I have come across a strange error when i press a button that i supposed to return to teh main activity i get an activity not found error. But when i dod it from another activity, it works fine.

Working call:

```
final Button mainMen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toMainMenu);

    mainMen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Menu.class);
            i.putExtra("Token", tok + teTok);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Broken Call:

```
maMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Campaign.this, Menu.class);
            i.putExtra("Token", player.tokens);
            // intent.putExtra("Round", player.round);
            // intent.putExtra("Rank", player.rank);
            // intent.putExtra("Score", player.score);
            // intent.putExtra("Sec", player.secondsTapped);
            // intent.putExtra("Min", player.minutesTapped);
            // intent.putExtra("Hour", player.hoursTapped);
            // intent.putExtra("Day", player.daysTapped);
            // intent.putExtra("LifeTap", player.tapsInLife);
            // intent.putExtra("SecTap", player.tapsPerSec);
            // intent.putExtra("TapRo", player.tapps);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

They are pretty much identical, but somehow the second one does not work. The first one has a bridging class before it. I looked through my xml file and nothing is wrong there since it works in one of my activities. The exact error i get is:

```
Unable to fin explicit activity class {com.tap.tapalot/android.view.Menu};
```

Thank You for Your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have used wrong imports, so that Menu class is not the Menu-class you expect.

Try to specify the Menu.class in your intent with full package-path.

Comment: Thanks A lot :) Fats Reply Ill upVote in 11 Minutes :) I cant yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check you seem to be importing. You are importing android.view.Menu in the second call. This is not your Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the wrong android.view.Menu class. You should import your Menu Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define 'Menu Class' in your mainfest file? like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="pakgae.name.your.Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Since Menu class is my Main Activity, i cannot define it again, it is already defined by default as the first activity in the manifest. But this can also cause this problem if the activity, is not a main activity, so this response is usefull for others. Thanks A lot :)

Comment: I think you must defined it in the mainfist `All activities must be declared in your manifest file, AndroidManifest.xml, using an <activity> element.` http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#AddToManifest